# how to generate triples by using sparql entailment rules in DotnetRDF?

Tags: sparql, rdf, dotnetrdf

I defined some classes in RDF file, and subclasses inherited from it by using protege as following:

- Person class.

  - employee subclass of person.

    - ex-employee subclass of employee.

for example if I have ex-employee instances I want to generate and insert them as instances for employee class.

also if I have employee instances I want to insert them as instances of Person class.

what I am asking for is how to generate triples based on inheritance relationship between these classes as following statement ?

```
Insert Into myGraphFile 
  {?newInstance rdf:type ?y}
FROM myGraphFile
WHERE {
?newInstance rdf:type ?x.
?x rdfs:subClassOf ?y.
}
```

how can I do this by using DotnetRDF?

Also I appreciate any example which illustrates entailment rules in sparql with dotnetRDF library.

Comment: DotnetRDF is just a SPARQL API. Reasoning functionality is given by the underlying triple strore. In addition, with SPARQL 1.1 you can cover something like transitive closure by property paths, e.g. `rdfs:subClassOf*`

Comment: @AKSW thank you for replying, my question is about using this API, is it possible to generate triples using DotnetRDF just like a way I mentioned above? any examples?

Comment: [1] SPARQL Update with DotnetRDF: https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Updating%20with%20SPARQL

Comment: [2] SPARQL 1.1 Update: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/

Comment: So, you have to load the data in-memory, then write the SPARQL INSERT query and then save the file - if that's what you want. I don't think that `INSERT INTO file` is valid - or better said, I'm pretty sure